# Show full size popup outside iframe but with content from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, popupwindow

**[UPDATED with test files]**

I am trying to show up the content inside of an iframe as (almost) full window size popup.

Following is the structure of the entire page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- no bootstrap -->
    <!-- no jquery -->
    <!-- some other ui framework libs -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=container>
      <div id=header></div>
      <div id=left-side-bar></div>
      <div id=right-side-view>
        <div id=top-bar></div>
        <div id=bottom-user-area>
          <iframe id=user-area src='mypage.html'>
            <!-- my content comes here -->
            <html>
              <head>
                <!-- jquery js and css -->
                <!-- boostrap js and css -->
                <!-- jqueryui js and css -->
                <!-- page specific js and css -->
              </head>
              <body>
                <!-- all my stuff that is the user interface goes here -->
                <div id=content>
                  <div id=input-area></div>
                  <div id=results-area></div>
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I want to pull the `#content` div inside the iframe to show up as full size popup on the whole page (outside the iframe). I don't have source code access to anything outside `<!-- my content comes here -->`

I am able to access the outer div `#container` using a parent hop and create a div `#popup` there, get the html content from `#content` and insert into `#popup`, use the jQuery dialog to show the popup. But I am facing a few problems I think I understand but am not sure how t get around it.

1. The popup is able to pick the styling but the button clicks and other
   events does not work. Maybe because the outer context does have
   jQuery and bootstrap loaded?
2. I am not able to resize the popup to the `#container`'s width and height. I assume a default width and height.
3. After fixing the two points above, I think I *might* run into a different problem - since the ids and events etc are same inside #content and #popup, will whatever happens in the popup happen in #content too? Or is the events etc contained within the context (iframe or outside). But if it does happen, how do I prevent that happening? Or maybe have it configurable.

Well, I think that sums it up. Bear with me if this write up is long or unclear. Like to know your inputs on how to get around the problem.

Your help is highly appreciated.

It was tough to simulate but I managed to code up the scenario as two files if you want to try out:

- [main.html](https://sites.google.com/site/kenbaselabs/files/main.html) - this is the main page. I don't have access to the source but that will just include my page as an iframe.
- [iframe.html](https://sites.google.com/site/kenbaselabs/files/iframe.html) - this is my page, and I want (part of the) content from here to show up as a full size popup

Accessing the parent window/document from the iframe was very tough. Chrome does not allow it owing to cross origin even thought they are from the same origin in this scenario and in the actual scenario. Safari allowed accessing the iframe's parent but did not allow modifying the parent. So for this test, I added a div `#popitout`, assuming that i will somehow find a way to create one (hurdle for another time).

Thanks in advance
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: I think you need to attach some jsfiddle in order for this to make sense...

Comment: Oops it is tough but sure let me give it a try definitely

Comment: @climbinghobo I managed to code up the files to simulate the scenario I am facing. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Is this some kind of code injection? why can't you access the html outside your code?

Comment: I am able to access the outer html. My problem is my content when popped out (as pop up) on the outer html does not consume as much as space (width/height) available and loses all the bootstrap and jquery stuff (the outer html does not include bootstrap and jquery libraries). Refer the samples attached in the question.